# JAVA: Parsing String to static final int value

Tags: java, parsing

I have simple problem, but I'm not able to fix it. I have this interface...

```
public interface KeyInput extends Input {

    public static final int TEST1 = 0x01;
    public static final int TEST2 = 0x02;
}
```

...this string variable...

```
String inputString = "TEST1";
```

...and this method.

```
public void doSomething(int _input) { 
}
```

I want to parse inputString variable to KeyInput static final int value. So that I could call....

```
doSomething(KeyInput.parse(inputString));
```

I know the enum valueOf, but this doesn't work here...

Comment: You need reflection here -- or an enum. Anyway, it looks like an XY problem, so what is it you want done?

Comment: You don't really know what you want to do. "parse inputString variable to KeyInput static final int value" is nonsense. The example makes it clear you at least know what you want the result to look like.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm reading some user defined values from text file and I need to convert those values to static final int values described in KeyInput interface. KeyInput is not my interface, so it can be changed by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only these two (or any other fixed number of) values, you might just enumerate them in `switch`:

```
public static int parse(String input) {
    int res = -1;
    switch (input) {
        "TEST1":
            res = TEST1;
            break;
        "TEST2":
            res = TEST2;
            break;
        // ... other options
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown string");
    }
}
```

The other option is to keep this values inside some map, so you can do this:

```
private static final Map <String, Integer> TESTS = new HashMap<>();

static {
    TESTS.put("TEST1", 0x01);
    TESTS.put("TEST2", 0x02);
    // ...
}

public static int parse(String input) {
    if (TESTS.containsKey(input))
        return TESTS.get(input);
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown string");
}
```

Still, if you see the enums as an option in your case, I can consider this solution:

```
public enum Keys {

    TEST1(0x01), TEST2(0x02);

    int value;
    private Keys(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here you'll just do `valueOf` as you suggesed:

```
public static int parse(String input) {
    return Keys.valueOf(input).getValue();
}
```

If all these options is now for your case, you should use reflection (though, I'm quite sure, it's not the case):

```
public static int parse(String input) {
    Field[] fields = KeyInput.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (Modifier.isStatic(fields.getModifiers()) && field.getDeclaringClass().equals(int.class) && field.getName().equals(input)) {
            return field.getInt(null);
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown string");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions and  broad summary ;) I also like KeyInput.class.getDeclaredFields(); method.